# PrestaShopException.php ignore modifications

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm trying to regenerate images for my shop in the backoffice but i get a ERROR 500 page without any stack trace or anything.

so i changed "_PS_MODE_DEV_" to true (and checked that's it's actually true in the code) but i still get the error500.html page content instead of the debug version with the stacktrace.

I tried wiping everything in 'PrestaShopException.php' but i still got the error500.html page content despite the fact that'PrestaShopException.php' is the only file using "error500.html" in its code in the entire prestashop project.

I need to get the stacktrace so i can debug. i don't have access to apache logs

I already deleted the cache folder but nothing changed, my modifications of  'PrestaShopException.php' are totally ignored and when i check the file on the server it's correctly modified..

Comment: if you can work your way through the request manually, Ie follow the way the code would run start to finish, you can throw an exception, to kill it ( so you know your good up to the throw) and then just work your way through it tell it breaks, or doesn't issue your exception.  While it's a bit tedious it will work.

Comment: another trick is you can create a custom shutdown handler http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php that might catch it.  I am assuming of course you already checked the server for error logs.